# Adding a Parent's ID to hidden field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm struggling, a bit, with MVC / Razor / Entity Framework.

I need to create an object which references a parent object. I have a field in my model, called ParentID, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to populate it with the parent's ID.

I'm thinking I need a hidden-field in my view, and then maybe place the ParentID in the ViewBag, and point that ViewBag property to the hidden field, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Something like this, was my assumption:

```
@Html.Hidden("BladeID", ViewBag.ParentBlade)
```

I'm not sure I've explained myself very well, so please ask away, and I'll expand.

Also, I'm not sure I'm doing this the correct way. This is all very new to me, coming from webforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `ParentID` is already in the model, why not populate the hidden field directly from there?

```
@Html.Hidden("BladeID", Model.ParentID)
```

If you really want to populate it from the `ViewBag` you'll have tot cast it back to `int` (assuming that's the type of `ParentID`), because the `ViewBag` is of type `dynamic`:

```
@Html.Hidden("BladeID", (int)ViewBag.ParentBlade)
```

**UPDATE based on comments**

If your view depends on two (or more) separate model classes you can always opt for creating custom a view model for that view, something like:

```
public class ParentChildViewModel
{
    public Blade Parent { get; set; }
    public Blade Child { get; set; }
}
```

and then use that class as the model in your view:

```
@model ParentChildViewModel
// more view code here
@Html.Hidden("BladeID", Model.Child.ParentID)
```

That said, there is, in my opinion, nothing wrong in using the `ViewBag` in this case, particularly if all you need is one property.

Comment: It's not in the model. I have two seperate models. One for the Parent type, and one for the child type. Is there a more correct way, then using the ViewBag?

Comment: @Nicolai - I've updated my answer to reflect the question in your comment. hope this helps